# Boundly-extended Wildcards in java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I was experimenting with Generics for a while and I've come up with smt i cannot explain:

If we have such method that return first element of a collection:

```
public static <T> T magic_method(List<? extends T> coll) {
    return coll.get(0);
}
```

And let's say we call it like this:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(12345);
System.out.println(magic_method(l));
```

So, my question is **What is actual returned type in magic_method ?**

```
<? extends T>
```

If we pass Collection of `Integer` does the compiler automatically "understand" that 
`T` should be `Number` (Since `Number` is super-class of `Integer`) ?

Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what `extends` mean in this context. Here `extends` means "`T` or a subtype of `T`".

Think of `? extends T` as a type specifier for something that could be assigned to a variable of type `T`.

Comment: Then why the returned type is an `Integer` not a `Number`?

Comment: The type of T is inferred (since you didn't invoke it as `YourClass.<Number>magic_method(...)`). When the type for T is inferred, it always gets the most precise type. In this case this is Integer.

Comment: And how the compiler detects the most precise type?

Comment: It sees that the argument type is List<Integer>, and Integer is more precise than any of it's supertypes (Number and Object).